# Nginx Conf redirect to a new referer Url in request paramter

Tags: apache, redirect, nginx

We want to add some rules in nginx.conf file to redirect a coming request to a new url that exists in the request paramaters. for example:

```
Http://<server1Url>/xyz?referer=http://<server2Url>.
```

The nginx.conf file should take the first URL and redirect to the referer URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter is available as an `$arg_` variable. The `return` statement could be enclosed within an exact match `location` block. For example:

```
location = /xyz {
    return 301 $arg_referer;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Answer (score 1):

Where NEW_FQDN is the new server to send the request to and ORIG_FQDN is the original server name:

return 301 $scheme://NEW_FQDN/xyz?referer=http://ORIG_FQDN/$request_uri;

If the new location exists on the same server, just use a rewrite instead.  In that case you can capture the referer directly instead of passing it as an arg.